# Creating an outline with JS / CSS that wraps a text

Tags: javascript, css

Say you have an image with `float:left;` and a text that flows around the image.

The code is pretty simple:

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="float:left">
<p style="outline: 1px dotted blue">Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

Is there a way to display an outline, that wraps around the text but not around the image. A normal outline on the text gives you this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

using a `display:inline;` on the `<p>` displays an outline on each line, not 'blockwise' oun the text's visible boundaries.

CSS3 is legit, any hardcore CSS/JS is permitted...

Comment: Is the image in the top left your only use case, or are you expecting to embed other images further down in the article?

Comment: It is and will be the only image

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this. Shift the image up and to the left so that it obscures the regular border. Then give it it's own border to complete the illusion.

```
<article>
 <img src="image.jpg" style="float:left">
 <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</article>


article {
 border: 1px blue dotted;
}

img {
 background-color: white;
 border-right: 1px blue dotted;
 border-bottom: 1px blue dotted;
 margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
 padding: 0 5px 10px 0;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KW45t/

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pollirrata/rKaHk/1/

It is not fancy but makes the job